# SlidingUpPanel with TabLayout and scrollable views

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-tablayout

My app uses the SlidingUpPanel library. The main sliding up panel holds a RelativeLayout and a LinearLayout as its two children. The TabLayout is in the LinearLayout. Two of the tabs contain scrollable views and the third does not. All of the tabs are fragments.

The sliding up panel works as expected for the non-scrollable view and handles the first scrollable event on the scrollable views. However, the moment I release my finger, the scroll capability goes away and the view sticks.

Looking at other stackoverflow questions, I have tried setting the drag view and setting the scrollview as the documentation suggests but no dice. The view still sticks after the first scroll event.

I also implemented a ScrollableViewHelper as the documentation recommended but that didn't seem to help at all.

Here is a video of the behavior I am describing
[image: ScrollableViewGlitch]

SlidingUpPanel documentation on scrollable views
https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel#scrollable-sliding-views

SlidingUpPanel Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/eventDetailsFullLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        android:id="@+id/eventDetailsSlidingUpPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/eventDetailsHeaderLayout"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/eventDetailsEventImageLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/eventDetailsEventBanner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="72dp"
                    android:layout_height="72dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/grey_circle"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/eventDetailsEventLogo"
                        android:layout_width="56dp"
                        android:layout_height="56dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_storefront" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/eventDetailsEventImageLayout"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/eventDetailsEventName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkDarkGray"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/eventDetailsTabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/teal"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/teal"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/gray" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/eventDetailsViewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```